# List with empty index

Tags: c#, list

I need a container for multiple items that should have predetermined amount of objects that may or may not be null. Like

`List<objects>` with capacity of 4

```
List[0] = new Object();
List[1] = null;
List[2] = new Object();
List[3] = new Object();
```

I need to be able to set any index to null without getting problems when iterating through the list even if all or some are null.

This is because i need each object to have a specific place in the list and i also need each place/index to be able to be empty.

I guess lists are not the correct option, what alternatives are there?

Comment: And why do you think `List` is not a correct option? Allows random access by index, and you can set as many elements to null as you like

Comment: A `List<object>` will work fine.

Comment: OK, i guess im just not doing it correctly then. Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list of `Object` (or any other type you want).

You can initialise it with a set number of nulls (or any other value):

```
List<Object> list = Enumerable.Repeat<Object>(null, 10).ToList();
```

And then modify only certain positions:

```
list[3] = "value1";
list[5] = 1;
list[7] = null;
```

Iterating over this list will work ok.

Comment: Also if he don't want a trouble while iterating through the list, it is better to check if index is null.

Comment: @RuneS Index itself is not null, just the value for that index.